# OpenSSL certificate is giving 'Invalid keystore format' in tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, tomcat8

I am using tomcat 8 and need to make it SSL, So I use openSSL to generate self signed certificate and configured the same in tomcat's server.xml file. But I am getting the below exception

```
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7443"]
16-Apr-2015 09:50:56.647 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7443"]
 java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1433)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:424)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:363)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   Write failed: Broken pipegMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
```

Comment: It is **not* giving 'invalid key'. It is giving 'invalid keystore format'. Don't be sloppy.

Answer (score 4):

That trace points to invalid format on your keystore.

Check this:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

Are certificates listed in your keystore?

If you generated it with OpenSSL maybe you are generating a pkcs12 and if you import this and use a [Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support) on Tomcat without specifying the format, according to the default keyStoreType value, it's setted as "JKS".

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

> keystoreType   The type of keystore file to be used for the server
>   certificate. If not specified, the default value is "JKS".

**Using keytool:**

I suggest: try to generate the keystore with keytool (for me it's easier):
https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html?jn45301e6e=2

Generate a keystore and self-signed certificate:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

**Using PKCS12**

Or if you pefer, you can also use a PKCS12 (if it's your case) with Tomcat:

Edit the JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security file and change the default keystore type:

```
# Default keystore type.
keystore.type=pkcs12
```

Then configure your Connector with something similar to:

```
<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector port="8443"
  maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
  enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
  acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"
  clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
  keystoreType="PKCS12"
  keystoreFile="yourKey.p12"
  keystorePass="endeca"
  truststoreType="PKCS12"
  truststoreFile="yourKey.p12"
  truststorePass="pass" />
```

Comment: Using openSSL  and the command used to generate the certificate : openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days XXX

Comment: that command does not generate the keystore, with this you obtain a cert.pem and key.pem and you should generate a keystore

Answer (score 0):

In my case, openssl.exe which Tomcat recognized did not match with Tomcat Native Library(tcnative-1.dll).
I downloaded them from https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native then ssl worked.